# Why does UDK require .NET 4.0?

Tags: udk

UDK engine requires that end-users install .NET 4.0, but what about Windows XP users?

Is there any way to get rid of that requirement, by perhaps disabling certain features?

Comment: According to the [readme](http://www.udk.com/readme), it only requires .NET 3.5. Also, .NET 4.0 works fine on XP, just update to SP3.

Comment: Did u know any thing about ignoring it , i mean this engine supposed to develop even osx , ps3 , games i know in udk it's limited , but there should be some feature so u can ignore to use

Comment: Also this requirement which you referring to is for engine it self

Comment: "Why does UDK require .NET 4.0?" and "UDK engine requires that end-users install .NET 4.0" ask different things. Are you talking about the Unreal Engine or the UDK?

Comment: Regarding your second question "Is there any way to get rid of that requirement, by perhaps disabling certain features?", No.

Comment: I am talking about UDK, And Why The Hell Down Vote ?! Man It's Simple Question , If You Don't Know If You Are Not Familiar With Development Why You Guys Do This  :(

Comment: @iamcreasy i am developing applications around 12 years , why you are so sure ?! i mean just NO , is there any proof to your statement ?

Comment: Watch your tone.

Comment: Closing as not constructive.  Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117048/can-i-ask-a-why-did-they-do-it-this-way-type-of-question

Comment: @synxmax your 12 year knowledge is not paying of as it should ;) That being said, I am sure cause in UDK you get a binary. To do the things you are asking, you need to get the source of it and remove the dependencies , which is not going to happen cause unless you get the source, and when you do get it, you *wont* be using UDK. :)

Answer (score 3):

UDK requires the .Net framework *for the map editor* - I assume if you don't package the map editor with your game you can skip this requirement; however, the UDK runtime installer will download an install .Net automatically (*"The UDK will install .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 if you don't already have it"*) - so you will need to install the UDK yourself (which is probably illegal). In other words you probably can't legally skip the .Net requirement. Overall this is not a problem for Windows XP users - and the .Net web installer that the UDK uses usually only downloads ~50MB (as opposed to the full installer which is well over 200MB).

The reason it works on iOS and so forth is because Epic Games have written a specific runtime that supports those targets; which obviously don't have the .Net framework requirement.